# Why did Dumbledore choose this verse for Kendra and Ariana's tomb?

Tags: harry-potter

> She pointed to the dark stone. Harry stooped down and saw,
>   upon the frozen, lichen-spotted granite, the words Kendra Dumbledore
>   and, a short way below her dates of birth and death, and
>   Her Daughter Ariana. There was also a quotation:
>   **Where your treasure is, there will your heart be also.**
>   <sub>Deathly Hallows - Chapter 16: Godric's Hollow</sub>

Is there any reason why Dumbledore (presumably) chose this verse to place on his sister's tomb?

Comment: I’ve always assumed it was his way of saying that his own heart was buried along with Ariana, his treasure.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The quotation is from the Bible in Matthew 6:21:

> <sup>19</sup> Do not store up for yourselves treasures on earth, where moths and vermin destroy, and where thieves break in and steal. <sup>20</sup> But store up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where moths and vermin do not destroy, and where thieves do not break in and steal.
>    <sup>21</sup> **For where your treasure is, there your heart will be also.**
>   <sub>Matthew 6:19-21 NIV</sub>

The premise is that Jesus is telling his disciples that their focus should not be on worldly gain because the real treasure is elsewhere.

In Harry Potter, we know that Dumbledore feels great remorse over what happened to his sister, her death being one of the key reasons he never accepted the post of Minister of Magic. Placing this verse on her tombstone is his way of acknowledging that he missed out on the greater treasure due to his misplaced ambitions - as well as providing a warning along with some advice to any who may read it in the future.

Comment: 'As well as providing a warning along with some advice to any who may read it in the future.' At least those who follow it or know what it means. I never actually thought about it and reading the quote you cite means absolutely nothing to me. The meaning is lost to me in that passage. One should always remember to truly appreciate what you treasure/etc. and not take it for granted but even if that is the concept I wouldn't be able to put that together from the quote. Still, iirc there is another biblical quote (related to Harry's parents?) which I don't understand either. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Pryftan There is a very large volume of material to further investigate what the quote means, if you really want to understand it.

Comment: @Pryftan: This answer does not explain the meaning of the verse well, which could be part of why you don't understand it. (This is a matter of meaning, which is a separate matter from whether it is true.) The verse is a roundabout way of stating that your heart (concerns and thoughts) will be (continually) on the things that you treasure, and therefore you should realize what is truly valuable (heavenly things) so that you don't have your heart in the wrong place (figuratively). If you take the verse out of the original context, it is actually quite true (as a psychological fact).

Comment: @Pryftan: The fact that it's been carved on a tombstone should be enough impetus for people who are unaware of that context to look into it more -- which it does, as this very question demonstrates. That applies even more to *the last enemy to be destroyed is Death*, which is the quote on the stone of the Potters, as it resonates strongly with the themes of the story itself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert 'some people' you mean. A word I don't know? Yes (though I have to be careful lest I get back into the old habit of reading the dictionary as a novel - and even looking up a single word I tend to look up adjacent words). But something like this? No. I'm more inclined to pass over it. The words *the last enemy to be destroyed is Death* is rather silly to me because I don't see it as an enemy but part of my mortality. And isn't that what makes Harry a master of Death (even besides owning the Hallows - though he discarded them)?

Comment: @Nacht I believe you. But I don't know that I would grasp the concept because spirituality (and whatever else it is) isn't something that I understand or need or want. I wasn't criticising the answer in any case - I was saying however that the warning as suggested isn't necessarily going to apply to any who read it in the future (which would suggest *all who read it in the future*).

Comment: @user21820 Yes indeed. Your last sentence is quite true. And I agree at least except for the very last part of the point ('so that you don't have your heart in the wrong place'). I think it's more true that it's *possible* for this to happen if you realise, accept and embrace it. But often it's hard to see these types of things and thus people do tragically take for granted those things (and people) they love and treasure most. People tend to be rather blind and self-centred (and I don't mean that everyone is self-centred so much as our lenses are our own).

Comment: @Pryftan: No disagreement with that caveat; people tend to take things for granted. Some might argue that it implies they don't actually treasure those things that much, but that would be an erroneous implication, it is far more complicated. But we must try to avoid taking things for granted.

Comment: @user21820 Absolutely. I certainly don't but many do. Even things like electricity I think about as being grateful [having it]. But this goes esp for things, animals and people you love. Those are most precious as a life is a one time and once it's gone it's gone for good. Tragically many people do take those they love for granted; it's a strange thing that humans tend to neglect the things they love until it's too late (if ever). Thus Emerson's 'You can never do a kindness too soon, for you never know how soon it will be too late. ' This is something people tend to forget or ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Dumbledore put this because he realized that his heart wasn't truly in to the goal i.e. the Deathly Hallows, which he was trying to attain alongsie Grindelwald. He might have been attracted to it only a little bit, of his own accord, rather he might have been blinded by his 'love' towards Grindelwald. He finally realized that his heart truly belongs to his family, this fact is even more true because we know that is what Dumbledore, like Harry, sees in the Mirror of Erised. He only realized the value of his family once they were all gone and seperated

Comment: Whilst a nice theory this would be improved if you could [edit] in any supporting quotes to back it up. The Mirror of Erised is nice evidence but there could be other reasons he sees them.